# Export only raw data from firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery

I am willing to export all my previous and all future firestore documents to Big Query as tabular format.

Example: If I have a `User` collection in firestore like:

```
{
    "name": "Jon",
    "score": 10,
}
```

Then the BigQuery table should look like this:

```
 -------------------------------------
|       id       |   name   |  score  |
 ----------------+----------+---------
| <document_id>  |   Jon    |    10   |
 ----------------+----------+---------
```

I have tried using

1. [Export Collections to BigQuery](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-bigquery-export?authuser=0). This does not export the data in the above format; it rather keeps track of the each insert/update/delete events.
2. Manually creating a table in the dataset and importing the backup from firestore. This does get me the BigQuery table view I want, but that is not updated automatically (like the extension does).

What do I do to achieve the tabular format of the document mentioned above as well as it updates automatically when the firestore documents are updated? Do I have to write my own cloud function to update all the data to BigQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [schema-views](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/blob/master/firestore-bigquery-export/guides/GENERATE_SCHEMA_VIEWS.md) scripts that come with the "Export Collections to BigQuery" allow you to create views that let you query your data in a more tabular form like you suggested. You can set them up once and then query against them even as new data comes in.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had tried that before but somehow it didn't work. Now it is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Export Collections to BigQuery. This does not export the data in the
>    above format; it rather keeps track of the each insert/update/delete
>    events.

As explained by Michael, with the "Export Collections to BigQuery" extension you could run the `schema-views` script, which is [provided with the extension](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/blob/master/firestore-bigquery-export/guides/GENERATE_SCHEMA_VIEWS.md), to create a view according to your desired data model.

---

Another approach would be to write a Cloud Function that directly writes to BigQuery. The following simple example shows how a Scheduled Cloud Function reads the docs from the `users` collection and add them to a BigQuery table.

It's up to you to adapt it. In particular, if you want to update the BigQuery table when the Firestore documents are created/deleted/updated, you should use an [`onWrite()` Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?authuser=0#trigger_a_function_for_all_changes_to_a_document).

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const { BigQuery } = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');

const bigquery = new BigQuery();


exports.exportToBigQuery = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 24 hours').onRun(async (context) => {

    try {

        // get the user docs !! UP TO YOU TO ADAPT THE QUERY !!
        const usersQuerySnapshot = await admin.firestore().collection("users").get();

        const rows = [];

        usersQuerySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            rows.push({ id: doc.id, name: doc.get("name"), score: doc.get("score") })
        });

        const dataset = bigquery.dataset("dataset-name"); // Use Environment configuration https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env
        const table = dataset.table("table-name");

        await table.insert(rows);
        
        return null;

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return null;
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I created the schema view by the `fs-bq-schema-views` and backfilled the data through `fs-bq-import-collection`.